# Авторизация через соцсети в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, соцсети

Я работаю с фреймворком laravel 10. Есть задача сделать авторизацию через соцсети.

Нашел в сети интересную [статью](https://habr.com/ru/articles/320046/) , но она устаревшая, тем не менее там показан подход универсальной авторизации и регистрации через соцсети. У меня вопрос, как быть, если человек зарегистрирован в соцсетях не с емайлом, а через телефон.

В статье описывает вариант получения емайла и авторизации в системе, либо создание нового пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Для авторизации через соцсети в Laravel используйте пакет [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/socialite).

В нем уже есть куча различных соцсетей и сервисов, через которые можно настроить авторизацию. При отсутствии нужного, возможно добавить свой кастомный провайдер. Все сервисы отдают только email, т.к. телефон это все же более конфиденциальная информация. Возможно в каком-то конкретном API можно вытянуть дополнительно, при условии необходимых прав/разрешений в нем. Но вообще, если email не указан, просто делают колонку email как null, т.к. все равно привязка производится по id конкретной соцсети.